# Page shows code rather than the result of running the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In localhost:3000/forum/new it shows my code instead of what it is supposed to be.

It shows this:

```
  New Forum

  link_to "Back", root_path
```

This is the code I have for this page:

```
 <h1>New Forum</h1>

 link_to "Back", root_path
```

It basically shows all my code. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
  <h1>New Forum</h1>

  <%= link_to "Back", root_path %>
```

You forgot the `<%=` and `%>` for your code.

Answer (score 0):

The .erb file process the embedded ruby in it to generate the corresponding html and syntax for it is `<%= embedded ruby %>`. If you only want to process the ruby code but have nothing to print use `<% embedded ruby %>`, note the eliminated `=` sign.